Constraint: Limit Location so that only two positions are possible

I want to use Constraint: Limit Location so that only two positions are possible. In this example I have a cube that can only move between Z=0 and Z=1. (X and Y movements are also excluded.)
I would, however, like the cube to be even more constrained: I would like the cube to ONLY be at Z=0 or Z=1, so that when I drag the cube it would "jump" on meter from one position to the other.

Limit Loc constraint doesn't have this kind of possibility, so you have to introduce an intermediate parameter between your input and the X Loc Transform.
In your example the simplest way is to add to the cube a custom property, click on the gear icon, set its name, type = Boolean.
Right click on its button  and choose "Copy as new driver", then hover over cube's X loc transform value, right click and choose "Paste Driver".
Now clicking the button will make the cube jump between X 0.0 and 1.0.

